# IEqualityComparer fails using two properties

Tags: c#, distinct, equality, iequalitycomparer

When I use this comparer in Distinct() it always returns false. Can't see a reason why.

```
public class IdEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Relationship>
{
    public bool Equals(Relationship x, Relationship y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;
        else if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;
        else if (x.ID == y.ID && x.RelatedID == y.RelatedID)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Relationship obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = (obj.ID ?? "").GetHashCode() ^ (obj.RelatedID ?? "").GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

The hash seems correct to me, but the ID and RelatedID comparison never returns true.

It fails, as I can check the result afterward and the output is not distinct using those two properties.

Comment: `The hash seems correct to me, but the ID and RelatedID comparison never returns true.` <= please provide an [mcve] with a comparison between 2 instances that should return `true` but currently returns `false`. **Also remember to override `bool Equals(object other)` as well when you can't provide the IEqualityComparer!!**

Comment: are you perhaps comparing objects where one is `""` and the other is `null`? this will cause the `GetHashCode()` to give the same value, but Equals` to return `false`. Note that this is **not** an invalid scenario - that's perfectly allowed. What *isn't* allowed is `Equals` returning true and `GetHashCode` returning *different* values. But ultimately, it would *really* help to see a full example here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine here;

```
static void Main()
{
    var objs = new[]
    {
        new Relationship { ID = "a", RelatedID = "b" }, // <----\
        new Relationship { ID = "a", RelatedID = "c" }, //      |
        new Relationship { ID = "a", RelatedID = "b" }, // dup--/
        new Relationship { ID = "d", RelatedID = "b" }, // <------\
        new Relationship { ID = "d", RelatedID = "c" }, //        |
        new Relationship { ID = "d", RelatedID = "b" }, // dup ---/ 
        new Relationship { ID = "b", RelatedID = "c" }, //
    };

    var count = objs.Distinct(new IdEqualityComparer()).Count();
    System.Console.WriteLine(count);
}
```

gives `5`, not `7` (which we would expect if it always returned `false`). Tested with:

```
public class Relationship
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string RelatedID { get; set; }
}
```

---

To illustrate this more clearly:

```
var a = new Relationship { Id = "x", RelatedID = "foo" };
var b = new Relationship { Id = "y", RelatedID = "foo" };
var c = new Relationship { Id = "x", RelatedID = "foo" };
```

we can now demonstrate that the comparer returns `true` and `false` appropriately:

```
var comparer = new IdEqualityComparer();
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(a, b)); // False
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(a, c)); // True
```

we can also show that the hash-code is working appropriately:

```
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(a));
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(b));
Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(c));
```

note that the numbers will change, but *for me on this run* this gives:

```
-789327704
1132350395
-789327704
```

The numbers don't matter - what matters is that the first and last are equal, and (ideally) different from the middle one.

So: the comparer is working fine, and the premise of the question is incorrect. You need to identify *in your code* what is different, and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies to all! It is working fine.

I was comparing objects defined similarly to Marc's answer. But, I did this:

```
var relators = relationships.Distinct(new RelationshipEqualityComparer());
```

and then sent relationships, rather than realtors, to the next method where the items were reviewed. Sometimes it takes another pair of eyes!

Thanks!

Comment: great to hear that you figured it out